# Downloading USB firmware

Tags: libusb, firmware, libusb-1.0, dfu

I am currently trying to use LibUSB to directly access the firmware controller on a USB device. How do I directly download firmware off a USB device so it can be modified later (using either the SCSI commands or the LibUSB library)?

Comment: Firmware of what exactly?

Comment: 99.9999% chance the answer is no. Also what do plan on using it for? Do you know what chip is used? Does it even have firmware? Probably not.

Comment: I don't accept that it is impossible unless all options are tried. Considering it has done as a proof of concept with BlackHat talks and Shmoocon with BadUSB devices. I reject you statement of it being impossible.

It is phison controller which uses an Intel 8081 microcontroller.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the product page or a complete model number? Also, do you mean 8051? I have never heard of a 8081.

Comment: Does this help: https://bitbucket.org/flowswitch/phison ?

Comment: Yes, Sorry. The  8051.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing you'll find to a standard here is the USB Device Firmware Update (or "DFU") protocol. However, there are a number of major caveats:

- Most USB devices do not have updatable firmware at all. The majority of devices have their functionality fully defined in hardware, or in mask ROM.
- Of the devices that do have updatable firmware, most do not use USB DFU to do so.
- Even of the few devices that do support USB DFU, most do not support the "UPLOAD" command to retrieve firmware from a device. (It serves very little purpose in most devices.)

If you run into one of the rare devices that *does* fully support DFU, you may be able to interact with it using [`dfu-util`](http://dfu-util.sourceforge.net/). However, this is very unlikely.

Comment: I don't believe this to be an actual answer to my question in any regard, only pointing out that a protocol exist of doing so, not directly answering the question.

The DFU spec has a "DNLOAD" in their but no reference of any code implementations of which I was looking for. 
However, thank you for drawing my attention to dfu-util.

Comment: @RenegadeTech I can't really give a more direct answer without knowing what device you're working with. There's no single answer that'll work for everything. (Indeed, for many devices, the answer would simply be "you can't".)